# how to add specific labels with margin in R ?

Tags: r

I would like to label specific points in a scatter plot in R 
I checked through internet but none of the answers could help me out

```
# I simulate a data
x <- rnorm(n=72, mean=102, sd=5.2)
# then I plot it
plot(x)
```

Now I want to label those point lower than 10 and higher than 60 with their index 
Is there any idea ?

Comment: Here is one way using `?text`. By *label with their index*, i am taking to mean the points position in the vector `x`. Define a vector of labels and use the `text` function to plot. `lbs <- ifelse(x < 10 | x > 60, which(x==x), NA)
plot(x) ;
text(lbs, x, lbs, adj=2)` ;

Comment: they are overlapping @user20650

Comment: I imagine they will, if the points are close together and you have a lot of labels within your specified range.  But you can try and tweak the position of the labels by changing the `adj` parameter, or leaving it out altogether

Comment: With that mean and sd would you get all of them labeled?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more efficient way to do this but you can use text() in a loop:

```
for (i in 1:72) {
    if (x[i]> 60) {
         text(i,x[i]+1,i)
    }
}
```

Comment: text is vectorized, so you can do `wh <- x > 60; text(which(wh), x[wh], labels = x[wh])`

Comment: `labels = x[wh]` will write the value whereas the OP wants its index so  `labels = which(wh)` should be better

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `which` to generate a numeric vector or just use logical indexing:

```
idx <- x <10 | x >60  
# and I suspect you want different numbers here since this returns almost all of the values
text( (1:72)[idx], 
       x[idx]-1,  # offset below
      (1:72)[idx])
```

If you want to label with some notion of keeping away from otehr points and labels you may need to use the directlabels package.